# How do I write into Textwrangler with Applescript?

Tags: r, applescript, sweave, textwrangler

I would like to build a shortcut for Sweave's chunck when I am writting R code.
I use Textwrangler and I am pretty sure I can do it with an Apple script but I know very few of it.

The idea would be to add where my cursor is :

`<<options, >>= 
@`

Does anybody could help me ?

Comment: You probably don't need the `r`, `applescript` or `sweave` tags. It sounds like you want to create snippets; most text editors support this.

Comment: Maybe some other people would like to add sweave chunk with a shortcut,that is why I put the tags.
Anyway, snippets keyword help me, thank you !!
Here the answer : [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/textwrangler/UExtz0JhQ_Y)

Comment: Glad you found an answer. Consider posting it as an answer to this question and accepting it, so others can see how this issue was solved?

Comment: I have found the answer here [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/textwrangler/UExtz0JhQ_Y)

Comment: Adding this applescript to TexWrangler works perfectly for me !

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "TextWrangler" to activate
tell application "System events"
    keystroke "<<options, >>= "
    keystroke return
keystroke "@"
end tell
```

Just run this script

Comment: How will "System Events" know that this must be keyed into TextWrangler?

Comment: should work now EDIT: i just tested it and it worked well